# ON/OFF charger has been removed from your pc

Tags: windows-10-v1511

Since the last Windows 10 update, I've been getting this notification *every time I boot*. Does anybody know what the heck it is? And how to stop it complaining at me?

[image]

My PC was originally an iBuyPower custom build, but I've swapped out a few components since. It has an i5-2550K CPU on a Gigabyte GA-Z68AP-D3 motherboard. Not sure if that might be relevant.

Comment: What brand is the computer? Have you checked with your OEM to see if they have an update to fix this?

Comment: It would help if you give us more detail about what kind of device you're using (make/model/etc).

Comment: You had an application installed, you upgraded, it was removed because of a known comparability problem with Version 1511

Comment: @Ramhound: Then why does it pop up *every time I start my computer*? It doesn't appear in my programs either and I've never heard of it before.

Comment: Because the driver is being loaded.  [Why](http://www.gigabyte.com/MicroSite/185/on-off-charge.htm) you should update your drivers......

Comment: [Google Search](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-update/onoff-charger-app-removed-message-on-every-boot-up/63eb3d2f-986f-4e8e-9c42-08985d05b5f0)

Comment: @Ramhound: Ah. I had no idea that's what that is. Never even heard of it. The problem is that Gigabyte's website is practically impossible to navigate. I have no idea what I'm supposed to be looking for.

Comment: @Ramhound: I tried at(@) bios as per the link and I ended up stuck with an inaccessible boot device error from Windows when I rebooted. I managed to get it to start in safe mode (after doing a windows restore to an earlier point for good measure and panicking a lot) and then after restarting again it seems like it might have sorted itself out. This is why I don't update BIOS drivers without a really good reason. This wasn't a good reason.

Comment: I suggested updating the driver not bios.